# Z-index trouble with flash and CSS IE8 and Chrome

Tags: html, css, flash

I have a website at [link text](http://lixmebel.com)

I'm having problems with the navigation menu on the left. In the following menu: "Галерия -> Проекти" the submenu that pops up is shown under the flash content, despite of me setting the z-index. This only happens in Chrome and IE. Firefox renders it fine. Does anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add parameter `<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />` to force using windowless mode in flash plugin. Now your flash seems to be in windowed mode.

Comment: Unless you actually need transparency, you should use "opaque" rather than "transparent". It will also use windowless mode, but is substantially more efficient than transparent.

Answer (score 0):

you should add attribute `wmode="transparent"` in `<embed>` tag